# How to extract text(citation) from file in java?

Tags: java, file, io

I have a file like citation.txt.

Content of a citation.txt file is -> This is my first question[1] in stackoverflow. I am doing my final year[2] project in java. Please help me[1-2].

Input -> File content.

output ->

```
      [1]    This is my first question(before 50 words of [1] square 
             bracket[1])

      [2]    in stackoverflow (before 50 words of [2] square bracket[2])

      [1-2]  This is my first question(before 50 words of [1] square
             bracket[1]), in stackoverflow (before 50 words of [2] square 
             bracket[2])
```

please help how to do this in java.....

Comment: I read the content of a file using FileReader and wrap the filereader in bufferreader.. i don't know how to read  the '[]' square bracket in file and number between like this [1],[2],[1-2]....

Comment: can any one suggest me how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively simple task that only requires the standard Java string functions (once you've read the file into a string in memory). In particular, `indexOf()` and `substring()` should be all you need.

If I understand the question correctly, you would start by calling `indexOf('[')`, then use the result to figure out what numbers to pass `substring()` to get the first substring you want. Then you would call `indexOf('[', pos)` where `pos` is the position just after the first `'['` you found, then call `substring()` again. Rinse and repeat until `indexOf()` returns `-1`.

Comment: Thank you Ixrec i found your ans more helpful.Another doubt i have i got the  substrings like this->"This is first substring"[1] and "this is second substring"[2]  and this is third substring[3].[1],[2],[3] these three square bracket will be repeats in file in many number of times...i want to do is saving the [1] ->This is first substring [2]->this is second substring and so on.IF after after[2], [1] and [3] occurs need to place [2]->this is second substring,[1]->this is first substring,[3]->this is third substring..i have to save the substring according to square bracket num.sry 4 bad english

Comment: 'i have to extract the citations from the text file

Comment: You could use parseInt() on the substrings between '[' and ']' to get actual numbers. Then you could simply use the numbers as indexes to an array that holds the substrings. This is also very standard, need-to-know stuff so it'd probably be faster to read a general Java introduction from start to finish rather than ask another question every time you don't know the function you need.